# Reference request: log Sobolev inequality for uniform measure (uniform distribution over discrete set)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, entropy

Suppose that $N \in \mathbb N_+$ is fixed and denote by $\mu = (\mu_0,\ldots,\mu_N)$ the uniform distribution on the set $\{0,1,\ldots,N\}$ (i.e., $\mu_n = \frac{1}{N+1}$ for each $0\leq n\leq N$). I am wondering if there exists a log-Sobolev inequality for the uniform distribution $\mu$, in the sense that $$\sum_{n=0}^N \mu_n f^2_n \log f^2_n \leq C\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \mu_n(f_{n+1}-f_n)^2 \label{1}\tag{1}$$ for some universal constant $C$, where $f = (f_0,\ldots,f_N) \in \mathbb{R}^{N+1}_+$ satisfies $\sum_{n=0}^N \mu_n f^2_n =1$. Of course, \eqref{1} is merely a discrete analog of the log-Sobolev inequality for the uniform measure on a one dimensional compact interval, which takes the following form:
$$ \int_0^N f^2 \log f^2 \mathrm{d}\mu \leq C \int_0^N |\nabla f|^2 \mathrm{d}\mu$$ where $\mu$ is the uniform distribution on the interval $[0,N]$ and $f \colon [0,N] \to \mathbb{R}_+$ satisfies the constraint that $\int_0^N f^2 \mathrm{d}\mu = 1$. I am aware of some literatures on log Sobolev inequalities for uniform measures on compact intervals (or finite Lebesgue measure) such as [this reference](https://msp.org/involve/2014/7-2/involve-v7-n2-p05-s.pdf), but it seems very hard to locate the precise reference for the corresponding result (for discrete state space) stated as in the form of \eqref{1}. Any help or pointer to related references are greatly appreciated (and I am not interested in the optimal/sharp log-Sobolev constant) !

---

Remark: when $N=1$, the log-Sobolev inequality \eqref{1} boils down to the well-known log-Sobolev inequality for (symmetric) Bernoulli distribution due to Leonard Gross (1975) that can be found in [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2373688.pdf) for instance.

Edit: Here $N$ is fixed and for sure $C$ can depend on $N$, but $C$ cannot depend on the specific choice of $f$

Comment: No. This fails when $f_1=\sqrt{N}$, $f_j=0$ otherwise (or very small if you want to avoid the value zero).

Comment: That is, there is no constant that is independent of $N$. Existence of a $C(N)$ should follow from compactness of the set of $f$'s considered.

Comment: Hello Christian: $N$ is fixed and of course $C$ is allowed to depend on $N$, but $C$ cannot depend on the choice of $f$ (as long as $f$ satisfies the stated constraint)

Comment: @ChristianRemling Are you aware of any reference which contains the advertised inequality of the form (1)? Since log-Sobolev inequality holds (in a continuous setting) for uniform distribution over compact intervals, inequality of form (1) seems very natural (as it is a merely a discrete analog of the continuous version); Also, your "counter-example" cannot satisfy the constraint imposed on $f$...

Comment: @FeiCao By scaling, the continuous version has $C \propto N^2$, so that's what one would expect here (one can see that one cannot do better, by considering $f_n = F(n/N)$ for $F$ smooth).

Comment: @MartinHairer Dear Professor, thank you for your comments... I thought this should be a classical result given the fact that its continuous version is treated in literature... but I am surprised (as mentioned in the post) that I cannot find a precise reference stating the log-Sobolev inequality of the form (1) for uniform distribution on discrete sets

Comment: You can find this result in Diaconis & Saloff-Coste ["Logarithmic Sobolev inequalities for finite Markov chains"](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-probability/volume-6/issue-3/Logarithmic-Sobolev-inequalities-for-finite-Markov-chains/10.1214/aoap/1034968224.full) in Section 4.2. Although for the circle, but the argument can be adapted for the line. The scaling is as explained by @MartinHairer $C\propto N^2$.

Comment: @AndréSchlichting Thank you very much. I am aware of the nice reference you mentioned as well. The issue is that the statement of the log-Sobolev inequality (in the context of probability theory and Marov chains) is a bit different from the form used by PDE community. Maybe that section contains what I need, but it seems that some sort of "translations of terminologies" are inevitable...

Comment: Yes, some translation is necessary, by coincidence, we needed this on the circle in a [preprint arXiv:2312.13284](https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.13284) and did the translation in the appendix Proposition 24 due to the lack of a better say more analytical reference.

Comment: @AndréSchlichting Thank you very much for this new reference preprint (which is very recent)! I think that's all I need

Comment: @AndréSchlichting If you don't mind putting your comments as a formal answer, I can give the bounty to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use the results by Diaconis & Saloff-Coste ["Logarithmic Sobolev inequalities for finite Markov chains"](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-probability/volume-6/issue-3/Logarithmic-Sobolev-inequalities-for-finite-Markov-chains/10.1214/aoap/1034968224.full) in Section 4.2, where the proof the result for the symmetric random walk on the circle with $N$ nodes is given and takes the form
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^N f^2_n \log f^2_n \leq C^\circ_N \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N} (f_{n+1}-f_n)^2 \tag{LSI$^\circ_N$} \,
$$
where $f_{N+1}=f_1$ (note that I slightly changed the numbering from the OP to the set {1,\dots,N}, which is more consistent with the reference). Then the inequality (1) of the OP can be recovered by noting that
$$
(f_N-f_1)^2 = \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} (f_{n+1}-f_n) \right)^2 \leq N^2 \sum_{n=1}^N (f_{n+1}-f_n)^2 .
$$
Hence, we get that $C$ in (1) can be estimated by $C^{\circ}_N + N^2$.

To apply the results from [Diaconis & Saloff-Coste](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-probability/volume-6/issue-3/Logarithmic-Sobolev-inequalities-for-finite-Markov-chains/10.1214/aoap/1034968224.full), we translate the more functional analytic form of LSI$^\circ_N$ to Markov chains, see also [Appendix A in arXiv:2312.13284](https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.13284) from where I took the material below.

The right-hand side of LSI$^\circ_N$ is related to the Dirichlet form of the symmetric random walk on the circle $\{1,\dots,N\}$ with jump kernel $K(\kappa,\kappa\pm 1)=\frac{1}{2}$ and zero else. Indeed, we find
\begin{equation*}
      \mathcal{D}(f,f) = \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{\kappa,\lambda=1}^N \bigl(f_\kappa-f_\lambda\bigr)^2 K(\kappa,\lambda)=  \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{\kappa=1}^N \bigl( f_\kappa - f_{\kappa+1})^2 
%= \frac{\delta^2}{2} \delta \sum\nolimits_\kappa \abs*{ \partial^{\delta}_+ f}^2 
\end{equation*}
The left-hand side of LSI$^\circ_N$ is the relative entropy of the measure $f^2/N$ with respect the uniform measure on $\{1,\dots,N\}$ defined by
$$
    \operatorname{Ent}(f^2) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{\kappa=1}^N f_\kappa^2 \log \frac{f_\kappa^2}{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{\lambda=1}^N f_\lambda^2}  = \frac{1}{N} \sum\nolimits_\kappa f_\kappa^2 \log f_\kappa^2 ,
$$
provided $f^2$ is normalized such that $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{\lambda=1}^N f_\lambda^2=1$.
Then, the logarithmic Sobolev constant is defined by $\alpha=\min\bigl\{ \mathcal{D}(f,f)/\operatorname{Ent}(f^2): \operatorname{Ent}(f^2)\neq 0\bigr\}$. The result in [Diaconis & Saloff-Coste §4.2](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-probability/volume-6/issue-3/Logarithmic-Sobolev-inequalities-for-finite-Markov-chains/10.1214/aoap/1034968224.full) implies that $\alpha \geq 8\pi^2/(25 N^2)$, which translates to
$$
  C^{\circ}_N \leq \frac{25}{16\pi}N^2 \qquad\text{hence}\qquad C \leq \left(\frac{25}{16\pi}+1\right) N^2 \approx 1.5 N^2 .
$$
*all exact numerical values and factors of two without guarantees*